# Unity 3D не стандартные тела программно

Tags: unity3d, 3d

Есть ли стандартные инструменты в unity для построения 3D тела не стандартной формы? К примеру вращением вокруг оси заданной линии? Или же какие - нибудь другие.

Comment: Нет. Ищи ассет.

Answer (score 1):

Пока что нет. Unity - это игровой движок, который работает с графикой из редакторов. На данный момент есть только создание примитивов.
Недавно Unity взяли под крыло компанию Polybrash и сделали [их плагин бесплатным.](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/probuilder-111418) Он позволяет удобно работать с геометрией, а в версии 2018 есть какая-то примочка, точного названия не вспомню, для докачки этого плагина.
Вероятно, его возможностей вам как раз и будет достаточно :)

Comment: Спасибо. Однако мне необходимо менять их в runtime.